# Privacy alternatives to keep sensible data secure?

Tags: privacy, vpn, sensitive-data-exposure

I often find myself connecting to the internet through the University network and since I have to authenticate in order to navigate I guess that the system administrator can easily see any connection that I make and monitor all of my traffic.

I would like some privacy but I don't want to pass through some shady service because I often login to websites that store sensible information and I also want to be able to log into my bank account without having to worry too much.

What alternatives do I have?

Comment: Since you even include the VPN tag - what problems do you have with actually using a VPN? Or do you ask for specific "non-shady" VPN providers in which case this question would be off-topic (since product recommendations are off-topic)?

Comment: I often read that a VPN provider can read my data and that there is a chance that they might sell or steal my sensible data's.
So in sense yes, I would like recommendation's or even a guide to set up my own VPN

Comment: "...a guide to set up my own VPN " - There are already [many and easy to find guides to setup your own vpn](https://www.google.com/search?q=tutorial+setup+your+own+vpn). There are also [recommendations on how to pick a VPN provider](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3973/how-do-i-pick-a-vpn-provider) at this site. And there are many [recommendations for a VPN provider](https://www.google.com/search?q=recommendation+VPN+provider) online from reputable sites.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an administrator see all of my info on shared, private WiFi?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121431/can-an-administrator-see-all-of-my-info-on-shared-private-wifi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a reputable VPN will solve some of your problems. If you are paranoid about 3rd party VPN providers snooping your traffic you could create your own. Here is a good guide https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/vpn/set-up-a-hardened-openvpn-server.

It check out this list for info on 3rd party providers https://thatoneprivacysite.net/vpn-comparison-chart/.

Note that I am very paranoid and have no issue using my chosen 3rd party provider.